Does a buck-boost converter serve as enough circuit protection for an automotive application?
I am designing a circuit for a automotive application which is meant to map voltage ranges between two airflow sensors (i.e. 1 sensor has an output range of 1.75-7.0V and I want to replace it with a sensor that has an output range of 0-5.0V). The basic components of the circuit are a opamp and a voltage regulator/reference to provide a bias (1.75V) into the opamp. The circuit requires a 12V supply.
I am currently looking at using a automotive-rated buck-boost converter such as the TPS552882-Q1 as my 12V supply source. My question is would the converter by itself already handle any under/over voltage conditions? For example, the converter linked is rated between 2.7V and 36V which covers the range of typical automotive conditions.
Is the buck-boost enough or do I need to pursue additional mitigations such as TVS's, crowbar, or other related circuit-protection devices? If so, why?
